# Missing \endscname inserted citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, unicode

I am new to LaTeX, and I have encountered an error that I couldn't fix myself.

```
Error: "Missing \endcsname inserted Три \cite{Бідюк2009}"
```

Неre is a simple document to recreate an error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}

\begin{document}
Один \cite{Congdon2006}

Два \cite{Koch2007}

Три \cite{Бідюк2009}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography document (`source.bib`):

```
% Encoding: UTF8

@BOOK{Congdon2006,
  title = {Bayesian Statistical Modelling},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  year = {2006},
  author = {Peter Congdon},
  pages = {573},
  edition = {2},
  owner = {Georgii},
  timestamp = {2012.04.01}
}

@BOOK{Koch2007,
  title = {Introduction to Bayesian Statistics},
  publisher = {Berlin: Springer-Verlag},
  year = {2007},
  author = {Karl-Rudolf Koch},
  pages = {249},
  owner = {Georgii},
  timestamp = {2012.04.02}
}

@ARTICLE{Бідюк2009,
  author = {Петро Іванович Бідюк},
  title = {Адаптивне прогнозування фінансово-економічних процесів на основі принципів системного аналізу},
  journal = {Наукові вісті НТУУ КПІ},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {54--61},
  owner = {Georgii},
  timestamp = {2012.04.01}
}
```

Both documents are encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Depending where your error happens, you should use `bibtex8` rather than `bibtex` to compile your bibliography as bibtex doesn't support UTF-8 encoding. Alternatively, using `biber` and `biblatex` could help.

Comment: @ArTourter thank you for your help, I'll try to do that. The workaround might be changing identifiers to English without changing the contents of the bibitems. I think, I close the question if i find how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is due to the citation key: it's not allowed to use non ASCII characters in them. So change the `Бідюк2009` key into `Bidjuk2009` or what you prefer.

Use `bibtex` and *not* `bibtex8`, which doesn't support UTF-8, but only 8 bit code pages such as Latin-1. Instead `bibtex` won't try to interpret any of the character with high bit set.

You should anyway consider switching to `biblatex`; the problem with citation keys would remain, though.

Comment: biblatex _and_ xelatex (or lualatex) would presumably solve the bib key issues, as well as all the rest.

Comment: @egreg, I think I am using `bibtex`, and not bibtex8. I don't know because I am using TexStudio and clicked the `BibTex` button there. Anyway, my mistake was choosing non-ASCII identifiers, so `pdfLaTex` reported errors. I will look at `biblatex` later and check if using the combination of `XeLaTeX` and `BibLaTex` will help with non-ASCII identifiers.